# Iterate multiple arrays into object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have multiple arrays, the first one contains the keys, and the others contain the values.

```js
Array[
  "name",
  "surname",
  "city",
  "age"
],
Array[
  "John",
  "Doe",
  "San Francisco",
  "27"
],
Array[
  "Nancy",
  "Doe",
  "New York",
  "15"
],
Array[
  "Maria",
  "Doe",
  "Texas",
  "30"
],
```

And I want to merge the arrays into an object like this:

```js
{
  "name": "John"
  "surname": "Doe"
  "city": "San Francisco"
  "age": "27"
},
{
  "name": "Nancy"
  "surname": "Doe"
  "city": "New York"
  "age": "15"
},
{
  "name": "Maria"
  "surname": "Doe"
  "city": "Texas"
  "age": "30"
}
```

How can I do it using js as the length, keys and values of the arrays can change.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: you may want to loop over `Object.keys(...)` of the first array

Comment: Do you have the arrays with the values in another array that you can loop over?

Comment: Your desired result is not an object, it's 3 different objects. Did you mean an array of objects?

Comment: @curiousdev `Object.keys()` is for objects, why would you use that on an array?

Comment: Use nested loops. Use `.map()` over the 2-dimensional array of values to create the array objects. Inside that, use `.forEach()` to create the properties based on the array of keys.

Comment: I was trying with Object.fromEntries like the example from @Nina Scholz, but I got error on nodejs as Object.fromEntries is not supported... but I got it and it is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map over the values part and create new objects by iterating the first array as keys and take the actual value from the values part.

```js
var data = [["name", "surname", "city", "age"], ["John", "Doe", "San Francisco", "27"], ["Nancy", "Doe", "New York", "15"], [ "Maria", "Doe", "Texas", "30"]],
    result = data
        .slice(1)
        .map(a => Object.fromEntries(data[0].map((k, i) => [k, a[i]])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I just have added `Object.fromEntries = data => Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(data, ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}) ));` as in nodejs Object.fromEntries is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your Array has semantic mistakes.

```js
//This is your Array in JS:

let array = [
  ["name", "surname", "city", "age"],
  ["John", "Doe", "San Francisco", "27"],
  ["Nancy", "Doe", "New York", "15"],
  ["Maria", "Doe", "Texas", "30"]
];

//we need to sepparete keys and values
const keys = array.shift(); // ["name", "surname", "city", "age"]

//now array has just values and keys has the first item of an array

let arrOfObjects = array.map(item => {
  let obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = item[i];
  }
  return obj;
});
console.log(arrOfObjects);
```

console:

[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "age": "27"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nancy",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "city": "New York",
    "age": "15"
  },
  {
    "name": "Maria",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "city": "Texas",
    "age": "30"
  }
]